# Foreign key from bit to int

Tags: sql-server-2008

Is it possible to create a foreign key where type of the first column is bit but type of the referenced column is int?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

```
create table X
(
  c int primary key
)

create table Y
(
  c bit references X
)
```

Returns:

> `Msg 1778, Level 16, State 0, Line 1`
>   `Column 'X.c' is not the same data type as referencing column 'Y.c' in foreign key 'FK__Y__c__34C8D9D1'.`
>   `Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 1`
>   `Could not create constraint. See previous errors.`

Also see [the relevant section in BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx):

> - The `REFERENCES` clause of a column-level `FOREIGN KEY` constraint can
>     list only one reference column. This column must have the same data
>     type as the column on which the constraint is defined.
> - The `REFERENCES` clause of a table-level `FOREIGN KEY` constraint must
>     have the same number of reference columns as the number of columns in
>     the constraint column list. The data type of each reference column
>     must also be the same as the corresponding column in the column list.